# CSS solution to display side by side images from matplotlib in jupyter notebook

Tags: css, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to display side by side images produced from matplotlib in a cell of a jupyter notebook ?

```
for i in range(3):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[2,2])
    ax.plot()
    ax.set_title('fig ' + str(i))
```

produces 3 plots in a column.
I would like to display them side by side without a subplot solution (images are independant).

Answer (score 1):

You can try running the following code in a cell:

```html
    %%html
<style>
    .output{
        flex-direction: row;
    }

</style>
```

Result:

[image: Notebook]

In jupyter lab you can achieve that by setting the output as a grid:

[image: JupyterLab]

Comment: Note this may affect other results in your notebook, to avoid that you can use a selector such as:
```.cell:nth-child(3) .output```

Comment: It works in jupyter notebook but not in the jupyter notabook lab interface.
Any idea ?
Found the class .jp-Cell-outputArea but no effect when changing with 'flex-direction: row;'

Comment: You can set a the output as a grid in jupyterlab:
```%%html
<style>
.lm-Widget.p-Widget.jp-OutputArea.jp-Cell-outputArea {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks. How CSS is confusing sometimes...
Why a simple float: left; on the .jp-Cell-outputArea does not work ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for answers.

Here what I have tested with success.

With jupyter notebook (classic interface) :

```
%%html 
<style> 
div.output_png {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgray;
    float: left;
}
div.output_area {
    display: inline;
}
div.output {
    display: inline;
}
</style>
```

With jupyter notebook (lab interface) :

```
%%html 
<style> 
div.jp-RenderedImage {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgray;
    float: left;
}
div.jp-OutputArea-child {
    display: inline;
}
div.jp-OutputArea-prompt {
    padding: unset;
    border: unset;
}
</style>
```